# Erlang Cowboy, Server Side Event, eventsource close and reconnects about every 60 seconds

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I have the cowboy example eventsource running on a local Debian server. For the code please see --> https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/tree/master/examples/eventsource

After about 60 seconds there is always a 'eventsource was closed' then a 'eventsource connected' message.

I am testing on the latest chrome browser on win10.

I cannot see any reason for this and I wondered if this something built into the SSE standard, that the connection is dropped at regular intervals.

The chrome debugger shows the following error message:
GET http://192.168.1.100:8080/eventsource net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)

Any thoughts?

MPC

Answer (score 2):

You're most likely hitting the idle timeout.

You can change it with the following snippet in the [cowboy example](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/blob/0d0e7d164c72799b48275c0c79a7a9d5c08e652e/examples/eventsource/src/eventsource_app.erl#L20-L22):

```
    {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(http, [{port, 8080}], #{
        idle_timeout => 15000,
        env => #{dispatch => Dispatch}
    }),
```

You have more information about ProtocolOpts in the [cowboy doc](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.7/manual/cowboy_http/)

Comment: Tried this out and your correct. It does seem to be to do with the idle time. Not sure why though since the eventsource example sends data to the client every second. This suggests that it is a client idle time? Thanks anyhow for the help.

Comment: The documentation states that the idle_timeout is

    `Time in ms with no data received before Cowboy closes the connection.`

Since in the spec it shous that it's a `timeout()`, I'm pretty sure you can set it to `'infinity'` instead of 15000

Comment: @mpc (sorry, I forgot to metion you in the previous comment, it may be useful to you)